Move chromium config to new computer
I saw that in other operating systems you can move your configuration by copying your current configuration to .config/chromium and when you install chromium it will pick up the configuration from there.
I saw that chromium is installed with brew install chromium --no-quarantine under /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/chromium but I don't even see where the configuration data is stored.
I removed chromium and installed it with the configuration stored in .config/chromium but it did not use it.
I use macOS ( version ???) and a MacBook.
Is there a way to save configuration data?

On macOS it looks like Chromium's state is saved in the following files/directories:

~/Library/Application Support/Chromium/
~/Library/Preferences/org.chromium.Chromium.plist
~/Library/Saved Application State/org.chromium.Chromium.savedState

(That should be independent of how or where Chromium was installed.)
So if you were moving from one Mac to another, you could try copying those across.  (I've not tried this, but it seems very likely to work.)
Moving between a Mac and another OS is less clear.  It may be that the contents of ~/Library/Application Support/Chromium/ (e.g. AutofillStates, ChromeFeatureState, Profile 1…) is common to other platforms, and so you could trying copy files to/from there.  (The other two locations are probably less important.)  However, I've not tried this either.
